# Transaction pending for 10 days now

Tags: transactions, mempool

I sent Bitcoin from one wallet on cash app to a wallet on black chair on November 8th for around $260 it's been 10 days now and it is still showing as unconfirmed. mind you when I sent it there was no question about what fee rate
to select from or that would have been selected at the fastest, obviously. Can anyone please advise me what I can do aside from wait til the end of time. I needed These funds 9 days ago. I thought this was the future of monetary transacting it seems more like something that should be on its way out frankly. Greatly appreciate whatever help you can do